# Attaching an event to a set of elements that require unique attribute values using js helper in cakephp

Tags: javascript, cakephp

Every link with the css class .addtobasket needs to perform a certain ajax call.
The action it's calling is 'addTobasket', and it needs to supply its data-productid attribute, but I don't know if that's possible in this setup.

This is what I have so far:

```
$this->Js->get('.addtobasket');
$this->Js->event(
    'click',
    $this->Js->request(
        Resources::url('Product::addToBasket', $product['Product']['id']),
        array('async' => true, 'update' => '#content')
    )
);
```

But as you can see the `$product['Product']['id']` needs to be replaced with something like `$(this).attr('data-productid')`

Is that possible, or should I just loop over the products?